# how do i fix this i keep on getting zero as my answer instead of my conditions

Tags: java, joptionpane, helper

How do I fix this. I keep getting zero as my answer instead of my conditions.
The school grading system for java where I keep on getting zero as my final answer. Instead of the IDE going through my code it just reads what the variable has initiallized and not input.

```
public class task_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        int Grades = 0;
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter marks");
        // JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Grades);

        if (Grades >= 85 && Grades <= 100) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is HD");
        } else {
            if (Grades >= 75 && Grades <= 85) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is D");
            } else {
                if (Grades >= 65 && Grades <= 75) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is C");
                } else {
                    if (Grades >= 55 && Grades <= 65) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is P");
                    } else {
                        if (Grades <= 55) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is F");
                        } else if (Grades > 100) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use `} else if {`instead of `} else { if{`

Comment: It this suppose to be using `JOptionPane`? Or is it suppose to be handled by a Scanner or a parameter to the java program maybe?

Comment: its supposed to be joptionPane

Answer (score 0):

You're not accepting the input from user. This accepted input should be set in `Grades` before your conditions start. Try this:

```
int Grades =0 ;
String input;
input= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter marks" );
Grades=Integer.parseInt(input);

//now apply your if-else conditions
// I tried simplifying your conditions
       if (Grades>=85 && Grades<=100) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is HD");
       }
       else if (Grades>=75 && Grades<=85) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is D");
           }
       else if (Grades>=65 && Grades<75) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is C");
               }
       else if (Grades>=55 && Grades<65) {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is P");
                   }
        else if (Grades<55) {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your Grade is F");
                       }
         else if ( Grades>100) {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error");
                           }
                       }
                   }
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: how do i do it where sould  the grade be initialized

Comment: @HasanAhmed try this answer

Comment: @HasanAhmed you can accept the answer by clicking the tick sign beside the answer